# JPA: Entity not created in the database by persist()

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

**Code**

My entity is defined like this:

```
@Entity(name="setting")
@NamedQueries({ 
    @NamedQuery(name=JpaSetting.FIND_BY_NAME,
                query="SELECT s FROM setting s WHERE s.name = :name"),
})
public class JpaSetting {

    // CONSTANTS \\
    protected static final String FIND_BY_NAME = "JpaSetting.findByName";
    protected static final String NAME_ATTR = "name";

    // FIELDS \\
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int m_id;

    @Column(name="name", nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String m_name;

    @Column(name="value")
    private String m_value;

    /* Classic getters and setters here... */
}
```

The service is:

```
public class SettingsService {
    @PersistenceContext(type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager m_em;


    private JpaSetting retrieveSetting(String p_name)
    throws NoResultException {
        return m_em.createNamedQuery(JpaSetting.FIND_BY_NAME, JpaSetting.class)
            .setParameter(JpaSetting.NAME_ATTR, p_name)
            .getSingleResult();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void save(String p_name, String p_value) {
        try {
            m_em.merge(
                retrieveSetting(p_name).setValue(p_value) );
        }
        catch (NoResultException e) {
            m_em.persist(
                new JpaSetting().setName(p_name).setValue(p_value) );
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem:** In the `save()`method, `m_em.persist()` does not create the entity in the database. The entity's id is generated (confirmed by debugging) and I can see the `select nextval('sequence')` request in Hibernate logs, but there is no create request.

The table `setting` exists (created with the generated ddl) and is empty for now. I could insert and delete settings using the psql client with the same account as the application uses.

No exception is thrown, everything seems to work normally.
Except the entity is not persisted.

I have another entity / service in the same application (using the same persistence unit) where the `persist()` works, but I can't find an obvious difference.

**Edit:**
I just tried to create the record in the database to check the `merge` case, and it doesn't work either. So, it's a more general problem, but I don't understand where it lies.

Comment: try putting a `m_em.flush()` after your `m_em.persist()` and tell me if any difference happens

Comment: Try to call `m_em.flush()` after saving.

Comment: I think at that time, when the exception is thrown you don't have a `session` anymore (so you need to recreate a new one), hence calling `flush` on that `m_em` will "fail"...not 100% sure since every situation is indeed different

Comment: flush could be a solution, but i think that you have to investigate to add a spring context and a transaction manager. You don´t have to worry about commits and flush!! commands.  Example: http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-with-hibernate-persistence-and-transactions-example

Comment: @j.con @Jens Adding `m_em.flush()` after the `persist()` doesn't change anything.

Comment: @AntuanSoft I have a transaction manager setup (see the @Transactional annotation on the `save` method). Or I misunderstood something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it.

It turns out that the `save()` method was called by another method of the same class, which was *not* annotated with `@Transactional`.

As I use the default interception mode `proxy`, the call from the non-transactional method to the `@Transactional` one could not be intercepted by the said proxy. Thus, no transaction was used, and the commit never happened.

I solved it by adding `@Transactional` to the class itself, since all its public methods should be transactional.

Comment: Perfect!!! related with transactional!! it always is the key about transactions, commits and rollbackls.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how the persist is working at all, your `try{ m_em.merge` creates an exception during the JPA process. That exception most likely will `EJBTransactionRollback` any query associated with the current JPA stack.

Since JPA doesn't commit transactions right away (they are committed at a later time which is determined by the provider when the best possible time is) that's why you see it generate an id in debug mode (though its never committed.) The reason why no exception is thrown is because you are out of scope by the time JPA closes the transaction and then throws `EJBTransactionRollback`; adding the `flush()` after the `persist()` will cause the transaction to be committed right then. You should see at that point the roll back occur and the exception thrown.

If I were you, in your `save()` method I would use your `retrieveSetting()` query and if there are no results then `persist()`. I believe the issue is with putting the `persist()` in the `catch` block, you can't expect one query of a transaction to be rolled back and another query inside the same transaction be committed.

Comment: "adding the flush() after the persist() will cause the transaction to be committed right then" - not exactly, the flush will flush any pending changes to the database, but that doesn't make the changes committed. But you probably only mean that you will get exceptions at the moment of flush, and that indeed is correct. Also note that a  NoResultException will not cause a transaction to be marked for rollback, so it is in fact safe to do that persist inside the catch handler.

Comment: The `NoResultException` is thrown by JPA's `getSingleResult()` on the NamedQuery execution, that's why I have put the 'create setting' case inside a `catch`.